# using spring.net with a web service

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, spring.net

i have an application that i would like to IOC up.  The user interface is via a web service.  Ive read about the composition root and that it should be the first point of user entry to the system and spring specify using the global.asax to achieve this.  Seems ok for a web app but for a web service is this really a good idea?

Also i cant seem to find any good examples of the code used in the composition root for spring.net.  Does anyone have any links i could use as a reference or maybe some other IOC library.

Comment: What do you mean by "The user interface is via a web service." Do you mean that there is a separate UI application that communicates with your spring.net web service?

Comment: How is the service implemented? ASPX? WCF? Nancy? Hand-rolled? Something else?